# Louvian method for desired number of community

Tags: networkx, social-networking

Louvian method's build-in version (import community) divides the network into communities which gives the maximum modularity. I want to divide my network into two clusters only.
I am passing the graph to the community module and getting 27 clusters but I want two only so that can be used for classification.
How can I do so?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are methods designed to return two clusters, sometimes called bisection, for example the Kernighan-Lin algorithm ([implemented in NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.kernighan_lin.kernighan_lin_bisection.html#networkx.algorithms.community.kernighan_lin.kernighan_lin_bisection)).

The Louvain algorithm is a bottom-up method which starts by consider each node as its own community. The method merges communities if doing so increases the modularity of the overall partition. The method stops if no such merge is possible. This often happens before only 2 communities are left, so the Louvain algorithm is not a good way to get a bisection. If you insist, you might try to tune the resolution parameter, which governs the size of communities found by Louvain. I think Kernighan-Lin is a much better idea though.

Comment: Sir I'm trying to do text document clustering by using community detection algorithms. Like I was trying to do so by using Louvian method but it's dividing words into 8 communities, so I took top 2 and manually checked the accuracy it's giving not that good accuracy. But when I merged all those in 2 and checked accuracy I got above 90 % accuracy.

Comment: for example I have a corpus of sports and polities documents so here I want two cluster of words only(one containing words related to sports and other related to polities), so here Kernighan-Lin algorithm may word fine. But Sir what should I do when I have three or more kind of documents in the corpus??.

Comment: Moreover Louvian approach (O(n log n)). is faster than Kernighan-Lin method(O(n2 log n)).

Comment: If you would like to specify the number of communities, have a look at stochastic block modeling.

Comment: I want to use Louvain for clustering a large-scale network. How can I identify the number of the required clusters since there is no parameter that can be configured for this purpose in the algorithm built in Neo4j?